# Unresponsive buttons after certain time

Tags: xpages

Today we encountered a strange problem. 
We have a XPage with some buttons, who id opened in editMode and bind to backend Notes Document.

We can press the buttons and the values are updated to the backend document. Via a partial refresh we see the new values.

So far so good.

But.. when we leave the XPage open for, let say 1 minute, without doing anything. After this period we try to click a button, we noticed that the button became unresponsive.
Is there a cause for this behaviour??

Comment: Frank - have you used chrome devtools or something like that to see if there is any communication with the server at all?

Comment: Marky, I see in the developertools of Chrome that the refreshid is triggered, but on the page nothing happened.

Comment: Frank - what is returned from the server? is it nothing? I was wondering if this is a session timeout issue?

Comment: You will only see a url like: XHR finished loading: "http://ld09.e-office.com/ajax/scoreboard.nsf/progress.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=89420E82669A45C6C1257A210023DBFB&$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3Arefresher" (refresher is the id of a panel who will be rehreshed). But also it happens with a categorized view. The twisty doesn't do anything. I was thinking, we access these XPages as Anonymous with the appropriate rights.

Comment: You could at least try this - nothing to lose - in the XPages Application Properties section set the session timeout to 30 minutes - see if that fixes it. If it is because the session is being lost this should help....if not then you've lost another 2 minutes of testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Never seen it happen in a minute, but there is a timeout setting in the server INI that defaults to 30 minutes, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem, but, not after a minute, but a few hours.  I have an onclick event tied to a radio button and after a period of time, if I return back to browser clicking on the radio buttons does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=extend-partial-refresh-timeout

XSP.submitLatency = 120*1000;