# Server side onclick events stop working after session timeout?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have a radio button group and some other drop down selections to filter a view.  These use an onclick SSJS event to change the view when the user selects a value.  I also have a onclick event in a link on the view items.  All works great unless I let the web page sit for more than 30 minutes.  Then the onclick SSJS events all stop working. I assume a session is timing out. Is this what is happening?

Of course, I could increase this, but, is there a way to detect in client side JS that the session has timed out so I could then refresh the web page? I don't care if I lose the values the user selected. But, having all these onclick events go dead on the user makes the page unusable until they refresh the page.

I tried the keepalive control from the Ext. Lib but that had no effect!

Howard

Comment: This was asked and answered a while ago in the thread called http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089378/unresponsive-buttons-after-certain-time/11089563#11089563

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ajax call returning you a session variable. Once it is gone you know the session has timed out.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I ended up adding a refresh meta tag set to 25 minutes (in seconds) and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: The RPC call (using what's in the Extension Library) always seems to work, even when the buttons on the page that use SSJS don't (after the timeout).